# STL list problem C

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl

I have list pointer in c:

```
list<int> * pointer = (list<int> *)malloc(sizeof(list<int>));
```

when I try:

```
pointer->push_back(1);
```

I get error, because malloc doesn't call list constructor. I know to do this in c++ with:

```
list<int> * pointer = new list<int>();
```

but i need this in c?

Does anybody know solution for this?

Comment: This makes no sense. C doesn't even have classes or templates.

Comment: `std::list<>` is a feature exclusive to C++, not C. And using `malloc` kind of destroys the point of having the standard container classes with respect to memory management. If you need to use `std::list<>`, you have to use C++.

Comment: There is no way to use STL in C

Comment: @DReJ - False, but you have to write wrapper functions. And/or know and exhaustively declare the mangled names of all the overloaded/templated functions.

Comment: @Chris: And use some assembly for thiscall.

Comment: @wj32 - True. Wrappers would be easier, if more of a pain.

Comment: Come on, guys: it's a noob question, but there's no reason to hammer the guy with downvotes, is there?

Comment: list<int> * pointer -> If this is going through, you are probably using a C++ compiler.

Comment: @Chris: Anyway in this case you need to build your wrapper in C++.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because these are different languages.  Just because one only has the text string "++" after a common letter in the name doesn't mean anything - this is the functional equivalent of trying to use a Java container in Python.

If you want to use STL, you have to use a C++ compiler.

Comment: Not to mention that C doesn't have templates, which are used in the code snippet (even assuming it wasn't STL)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "placement" version of new(). to invoke the constructor on a chunk of memory allocated by malloc().

```
/* allocate memory using malloc */
list<int> * pointer = (list<int> *)malloc(sizeof(list<int>));

/* invoke the C++ constructor using the placement version of new */
pointer = new(pointer) list<int>();
```